# Link spans entire screen even when width is lowered

Tags: html, css

Have a link on an h1 and no matter what css I provide it always spans across the whole page. I only want the h1 to be clickable.

[image]

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z5bgsoLz/)

```
<section>
  <a href="about.html" target="_blank"><h1>
 About Me
 </h1></a>
</section>

 section a {
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 40vw;
      box-sizing: content-box;
    }

    section a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    section h1 {
      width: 40vw;
      box-sizing: content-box;
    }

    section {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: black;
    }
```

Comment: @Fil The whole width of the screen adjacent with the h1 is clickable, I only want the area the h1 is actually in to be clickable

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you put the a inside the h1, that would do it.

```html
<h1><a href="about.html" target="_blank">About Me</a></h1>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: do you know of a way to make it work outside of the h1? I can put it in the h1 but would have to change a bunch of the styles in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  <style>
        .abcd {
            width: 40vw;
        }
        section a {
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 40vw;
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }

        section a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        section h1 {

            box-sizing: content-box;
        }

        section {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: black;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <section class="abcd">
        <h1>
 <a href="about.html" target="_blank">About Me</a></h1>
    </section>

</body>
```

It was picking up some default section so added a class to have it take up only a certain size (you may ignore this if you don't like) and also made changes to  and  in HTML and now only About me is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code means that you are making the entire adjacent clickable

```
<a href="about.html" target="_blank"><h1> About Me</h1></a>
```

Becuase the `h1` tag is an entire adjacent, while this one

```
<h1><a href="about.html" target="_blank"> About Me</a></h1>
```

Focus only on the text `About Me`

Use the latter as a solution.

If you would like to use the anchor tag `a` outside `h1` tag, add this `position: absolute;` and adjust the width in your style.

For Example:

```
  section h1 {
    width: 10vw;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
  }
  section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Thay way you can make **About Me** as the only clickable